# Run NodeJS bat file and finish the process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to run a bat file with child_process module in NodeJS but I want the application to stop and the bat file to continue processing without waiting for the result of the application.

**Code I used:**

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec("start cmd /c my.bat");
```

Comment: child process option "detached" is what you are looking for

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. Can you show an example code?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#optionsdetached